# Convert pandas single column to Scipy Sparse Matrix

Tags: pandas, scipy, sparse-matrix, sklearn-pandas

I have a pandas data frame like this:

```
     a                           other-columns
   0.3 0.2 0.0 0.0 0.0...        ....
```

I want to convert column `a` into SciPy sparse CSR matrix. `a` is a probability distribution. I would like to convert without expanding `a` into multiple columns.

This is naive solution with expanding `a` into multiple columns:

```
  df = df.join(df['a'].str.split(expand = True).add_prefix('a')).drop(['a'], axis = 1)
  df_matrix = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(df.values)
```

But, I don't want to expand into multiple columns, as it shoots up the memory. Is it possible to do this by keeping `a` in 1 column only?

EDIT (Minimum Reproducible Example):

```
 import pandas as pd
 from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
 d = {'a': ['0.05 0.0', '0.2 0.0']}
 df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
 df = df.join(df['a'].str.split(expand = True).add_prefix('a')).drop(['a'], axis = 1)
 df = df.astype(float)
 df_matrix = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(df.values)
 df_matrix
```

Output:

```
 <2x2 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
with 2 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

I want to achieve above, but, without splitting into multiple columns. Also, in my real file, I have 36 length string (separated by space) columns and millions of rows. It is sure that all rows will contain 36 spaces.

Comment: How many rows do you have?

Comment: I don't quite follow.  Is  `df['a']` a simple numeric series, or is an object dtype, with arrays or lists of elements?  If object, do all elements contain the same length objects?

Comment: If you want more help, provide a [mcve]

Comment: Hi @hpaulj, it is an object type with a string of float numbers separated by space. The string, if split by space, will always produce same number of elements.

Comment: Hi @hpaulj, I added a minimum reproducible example. Hope it helps to understand the problem.

Comment: Why don't you parse this as an actual array from your file? Whatever has brought you to this point is the problem - fix that.

Comment: Hi @CJR, fair point. I can't seem to avoid the steps before this point, but, I can definitely write this as a CSV and read it back as an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Also, in my real file, I have 36 length string (separated by space) columns and millions of rows. It is sure that all rows will contain 36 spaces.

[Convert large csv to sparse matrix for use in sklearn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61757726/convert-large-csv-to-sparse-matrix-for-use-in-sklearn)

I can not overstate how much you should not do the thing that follows this sentence.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['0.05 0.0', '0.2 0.0'] * 100000})
chunksize = 10000

sparse_coo = []
for i in range(int(np.ceil(df.shape[0]/chunksize))):
    chunk = df.iloc[i * chunksize:min(i * chunksize +chunksize, df.shape[0]), :]
    sparse_coo.append(sparse.coo_matrix(chunk['a'].apply(lambda x: [float(y) for y in x.split()]).tolist()))

sparse_coo = sparse.vstack(sparse_coo)
```

Comment: Hi @CJR, you said so assertively, that I should not use it. Is it because code is too complex, or is it because it is not a good practice? Based on your suggestion, I am currently writing the file and reading it back as array and it seems to work, only that it is too slow for 56 Million rows and 36 columns. Between this and that, what would you advise to do?

Comment: Also, does this solution preserve the order of original dataframe?

Comment: You clearly read this in from something (you've said it's a space-separated file). This solution will fix your stated problem (and will retain order), but your real problem is that somehow you've parsed your perfectly reasonable file into a dataframe of unparsed strings containing many separate numbers. Going back to atone for that original sin is the correct choice, not this hacky fix.

Comment: Also, for the record, your data is not large. Large data does not fit as a dense array into memory of a standard laptop I can buy from walmart. Your data is small. It seems large because working with the data structure you have constructed has to be a complete nightmare.

Comment: Hi @CJR, even if I drop Pandas data frame completely, and read these 56 million rows of numbers as a NumPy array, it takes a lot of time. Also, not sure, why you say my dense array fits in main memory, it does not. My Pandas data frame with one column containing all the strings does fit in the memory, but, it is not standard laptop, but a server-grade machine containing 128 GB of RAM.

Comment: Can you just answer one question: Why does reading a file containing 56 million rows and 36 space-separated columns containing float numbers into a NumPy array takes ages? Here is the follow-up question, I asked after taking your suggestion into account: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63292290/read-a-file-as-scipy-sparse-matrix-directly

Comment: by the way, this answer solves my temporary problem by converting Pandas data frame into a sparse matrix into chunks. But, as you can see, it still takes a lot of time: whether I convert into a sparse matrix using this answer or I read my file as an array. So, my problem is far from being solved. Now the problem is not about memory but, the time it takes it to convert this whole data frame into a sparse matrix. Even if I read the file into an array (and avoid whole data frame), it takes a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

You could get the dense array from the column without the expand:

```
In [179]: df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

e.g.

```
In [180]: np.array(df['a'].str.split().tolist(),float)                                               
Out[180]: 
array([[0.05, 0.  ],
       [0.2 , 0.  ]])
```

But I doubt if that saves much in memory (though I only have a crude understanding of `DataFrame` memory use.

You could convert each string to a sparse matrix:

```
In [190]: def foo(astr): 
     ...:     alist = astr.split() 
     ...:     arr = np.array(alist, float) 
     ...:     return sparse.coo_matrix(arr) 
                                                                                               
In [191]: alist = [foo(row) for row in df['a']]                                                      
In [192]: alist                                                                                      
Out[192]: 
[<1x2 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 1 stored elements in COOrdinate format>,
 <1x2 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 1 stored elements in COOrdinate format>]
In [193]: sparse.vstack(alist)                                                                       
Out[193]: 
<2x2 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 2 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
```

I tried to make the `coo` directly from the `alist`, but that didn't trim out the zeros.  There's just as much conversion, but if sufficiently sparse (5% or less) it could save quite a bit on memory (if not time).

`sparse.vstack` combines the `data,rows,cols` values from the component matrices to define a new `coo` matrix.  It's most straight forward way of combining sparse matrices, if not the fastest.

Looks like I could use `apply` as  well

```
In [205]: df['a'].apply(foo)                                                                         
Out[205]: 
0      (0, 0)\t0.05
1       (0, 0)\t0.2
Name: a, dtype: object
In [206]: df['a'].apply(foo).values                                                                  
Out[206]: 
array([<1x2 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 1 stored elements in COOrdinate format>,
       <1x2 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 1 stored elements in COOrdinate format>], dtype=object)
In [207]: sparse.vstack(df['a'].apply(foo))                                                          
Out[207]: 
<2x2 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 2 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
```

Comment: Hi @hpaulj, you are right, it does not seem to save memory as I am still getting memory errors. Thanks for the attempt, though (upvoted).

Comment: Hi @hpaulj, in your second solution with function `foo`, with `apply` and `sparse.vstack` does it preserve the order of original dataframe?

Comment: Hi @hpaulj, do you think, it is possible to do it in chunks, rather than line by line. I have 56 million lines.