# Read a file as SciPy sparse matrix directly

Tags: scipy, sparse-matrix

Is it possible to read a space separated file, with each line containing float numbers directly as SciPy sparse matrix?

Comment: You can read any text file with basic Python methods, and split and convert lines.  But how that serves as input to a `scipy.sparse` constructor is up to you.  There isn't an out-of-the-box reader for this.  Only you know how the text numbers relate to the sparse matrix!

Comment: @hpaulj, thank you for the input. I read it as numpy array and converted it into sparse matrix. But, that process takes a lot of time for 56 million rows. Each row is space separated float numbers and text form of  '0.0' is not to be entered in the resulting csr matrix. All the non-zero floats need to be added.

Comment: I feel the way you can read `np.loadtxt`, the load of sparse matrix should also be possible. Usually text form of 0 can be treated as 0 for sparse matrix, unless I missed something.

Comment: I forgot, you already asked about making the sparse matrix from strings in a pandas series.  Nothing new here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61757726/convert-large-csv-to-sparse-matrix-for-use-in-sklearn

Comment: Hi @CJR, I will have a look. Thanks for sharing. Though, I have a much bigger dataset with 56 million rows and 36 numbers in each row, which I want to convert into sparse matrix.

Comment: Hi @CJR, the solution in the link is taking a lot of time in reading the file containing 56 million rows into sparse matrix. I have been waiting for more than half an hour for this. This is as good as reading the file as numpy as an array and converting that into sparse array. What I want is a bit quicker solution than this.

Comment: It's slow because you're parsing string data into numbers. Read it in once and then put it into an hdf5 file that'll load at whatever your I/O bottleneck is. Keeping what I can only imagine is 50 gb of unicode around is not an efficient way to handle this problem.

Comment: Also, this entire thing should take maybe 10 minutes from text; if it's taking more than that either you're also having to decompress it on the fly or there is some bottleneck between your file and your code. If this is over some shared gigabit network there's a sysadmin somewhere out there plotting to murder you.

Comment: Hi @CJR, yes, the problem seems to be indeed that I am parsing the data line by line and then converting each line from string to floats. I have posted an answer using pandas dataframe and not hdf5, which takes around 6 minutes for me to convert the whole file into sparse matrix. May be, there is a better solution. Please do post it. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: I'm glad you got it working. I would *strongly* encourage you to write that data structure out into a binary file (like an hdf5 file) so that you can easily load it directly into a sparse matrix if you need it again.

Comment: Hi @CJR, yes, on a little bit of searching more, there seems to be good ways of saving and loading sparse matrices  `scipy.sparse.save_npz` for repetitive use.

Answer (score 0):

**Given**: A space separated file containing ~56 million rows and 25 space separated floating point numbers in each row with a lot of sparsity.

**Output**: Convert the file into SciPy CSR sparse matrix as fast as possible

May be there are better solutions out there, but this solution worked for me after a lot of suggestions from @CJR (some of which I couldn't take into account).

Also, may be there is a better solution using hdf5, but, this is the solution using Pandas dataframe and finishes up in 6.7 minutes and takes around 50 GB of RAM on a 32 core machine for 56,651,070 rows and 25 space separated floating point numbers in each row with a lot of sparsity.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sps
import pandas as pd
import time
import swifter

start_time = time.time()
input_file_name = "df"
sep = " "
df = pd.read_csv(input_file_name)
df['array_column'] = df['array_column'].swifter.allow_dask_on_strings().apply(lambda x: np.fromstring(x, sep = sep), axis =1)
df_np_sp_matrix = sps.csr_matrix(np.stack(df['array_column'].to_numpy()))
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Output:

```
--- 406.22810888290405 seconds ---
```

Matrix Size.

```
df_np_sp_matrix
```

Output:

```
<56651070x25 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
with 508880850 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```