# How to transform a sparse matrix in batches

Tags: python, pandas, memory, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a dataset with approximately 3000 features. I got that by creating a sparse set from a TF-IDF that created approximately 1500 features, and a second TF-IDF that created another 1500 features.

When I created the first TF-IDF, I joined it to my pandas feature set, and I was able so sparsify that with `csr_matrix` no problem. So I know it's possible with 1500 sparse features. But when I try to sparsify the full 3000-feature set, I get a memory error because it required 33 GB RAM and I only have 16.

I'm assuming it's possible to sparsify such a large dataframe, I just don't know how. Can I combine two sparse matrices? Is it possible to do half the data and then add on the other half? Or is there some argument in `csr_matrix` that I've missed? I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61782027/7287543) suggestion, but it sounds woefully inefficient.

Is there just some alternative that I'm completely missing?

Comment: maybe not row-wise, but can you split your matrix at every, say, n=10000 row and sparsify all the chunks individually?

Comment: @Botond I did that and it worked, thanks. I figured if I can do the first half, and the second half is the same size, let me sparsify each half then just mash them together with an `hstack`, and it actually worked.